# How Jackson will generate a pojo from json schema having oneOf

Tags: json, jackson2

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "street_address" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "city" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "state" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf" : [{
            "required" : ["city"]
        }, {
            "required" : ["state"]
        }
    ],
    "required" : [
        "street_address"
    ],
    "additionalProperties" : false
}
```

What will be the Java class for this json schema?
When I generated the class, there were no properties like street address in the class

Answer (score -1):

```
class One{
String streetAddress;
String city;
String state;

// put getters and setters for each of the member variables.

}
```

I hope, Your query will resolve :)

Comment: But the validation is not happening, even if I pass both city and state it does not throw any error